# How do I create an SQL table only if it doesn't exist?

Tags: android, mysql

I am programming in Android and am trying to make an SQL database to store highscores. In my `onCreate` method, I have

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORES + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_SCORE + " TEXT" + ");";
db.execSQL(query);
```

where `TABLE_SCORES` is the table name and the `COLUMNS` are my columns.

When I run the app, it works the first time and saves, but crashes the second time. In the logs, it says that it was unable to compile my query. I have already tried `IF NOT EXISTS` but it did not help.

Comment: If you already tried `if not exists` then the error lies in the code part of you app which you don't show and not in the query itself

Comment: Agreed I would expect this to send a SQL error that the table already exists.

Comment: Please post a complete error stack trace from logcat (use EDIT to edit the post, do not post an answer or another question).

Comment: Where did you try `if not exists`? It should be after `TABLE` and before the table name.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `IF NOT EXISTS` after `CREATE TABLE`!

Answer (score 1):

you should subclass [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), implement `public abstract void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db)`, and put your create query there. onCreate is called just once, the first time the database is created. This way you can avoid checking if the table exits or not

Comment: A good beginner tutorial on databases in Android, if OP is curious: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html